# MS Graph API Authentication on Embedded device without a browser

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What is the best way to do this. I can not find a link. Almost every example is using OAuth2 and native app version of the examples still wants the client app to pop up a browser.

My system does not have a browser. I can make REST requests but that is it.

I just want to use a simple client that can list things on a command line app just by using Outlook.com or Hotmail account. Not for a Work/School account (no Active Directory).

Long story short I don't want to be redirected to a website. I can make `http` request and parse the response.

These are my limitations. All implementations are in C or c++. Are there an examples with flow diagram?

Comment: You can do the authentication on a separate machine and just move in the authentication token, assuming this has to be done only once. I wouldn't imagine multiple users authenticating themselves on an embedded device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what you're looking for is the `client_credentials` grant. You can read about setting this up @ [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

This grant has some limitations. In particular, it only supports Work/School Accounts. This is because your application will require the consent of an administrator, something not available with a personal Microsoft Account (Outlook.com, XBox Live, etc.). You'll need an Active Directory to authenticate against. You can however set up [Azure Active Directory for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/).